# Q: Is the password hash in $user not beplaced by *

Tags: cakephp, passwords, cakephp-3.0

In my old cakephp 2.x Applications, the password hash was hidden by '*' when I retrieved the data from the User Model. I am not a hundret percent shure, but I think this was done automaticly by Cake.

Now testing Cakephp3.0, I am surprised finding the complete hash when retrieving data from the User Model.

I got a few questions concerning this password-hash-hiding:

- Am I right with my opinion this was a function in cakephp2?
- Does anyone know, why this function was not implemented in Cakephp3 and why?
- If I am wrong by assuming this was included in cake, where is the place to implement this functionality in cake2 and cake3?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm curious why you want this *** behavior on user data ([I implemented the db-credentials filter](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/fcd0505d424aaafecfe3b051930e721efebac9f5))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I right with my opinion this was a function in cakephp2?

Yes, in Cake 2.x this is part ot the Debugger, the data itself however is not being touched, just some of the content is being masked when outputting the data.

> Does anyone know, why this function was not implemented in Cakephp3 and why?

It is still implemented, but it has been moved. The whole point of this masking thingy was to avoid accidental exposure of datasource credentials (mainly in error messages/pages), it never really had something to do with possible user model data, this is just a side effect for data that happens to use keys like `password`.

So in 3.x this functionality has been moved to `\Cake\Database\Connection::__debugInfo()`

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/4542**

This ensures that you'll still end up with masked credentials when for example debugging connection objects, being it explicitly, or implicitly on error pages, while it doesn't obstruct debugging other data anymore.

[image]

> [...], where is the place to implement this functionality in [...] cake3?

This highly depends on your use case, if you'd for example wanted to have it masked in debug output, then you could implement it in an overriden `__debugInfo()` method in your user entity class, similar to how the `Connection` class is doing it.

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.11/src/Database/Connection.php#L702**

Of course this would only work for entities, not for non-hydrated data (array data).